# Switch column if value is found in an array

Tags: bash

If the table contains a string from the file I need to replace the with a '-' and then change column four to what ever column two had.

I have the following .txt file:

```
0
1
2
```

and I have a csv:

```
carrot, 0, cat, r
orange, 2, cat, m
banana, 4, robin, d
```

output:

```
carrot, -, cat, 0
orange, -, cat, 2
banana, 4, robin, d
```

What I've currently got is I have done a for loop for the csv file line by line and used grep to change if it contains the word. If greater than one replace it with a dash. I think this method is very inefficient and was wondering if there was a better method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is classical case for **`awk`** tool:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS = OFS = ", " }
     NR == FNR{ a[$1]; next }
     { if ($2 in a) { $4 = $2; $2 = "-" } }1' file.txt file.csv
```

The output:

```
carrot, -, cat, 0
orange, -, cat, 2
banana, 4, robin, d
```

Comment: Is there any way I can input 2 and 4 as a shell variable?

Comment: @JohnnyJohnston, that would depend on your conditions. You can pass variables to awk script with `awk -v var1="$some_var" ...`